# Use java to access a WCF service with TransportWithMessageCredentials (UserName)

Tags: java, .net, wcf, basichttpbinding

I have developed a WCF service that uses BasicHttpBinding with TransportWithMessageCredentials and custom username and password validation. I have a client who needs to interface with my service, but the client uses Java. Not being a Java programmer myself, I can't help him much. So I thought I would extend the question to the SO community. Can you guys shed some light here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should not be hard. For `BasicHttpBinding` `TransportWithMessageCredentials` means that it is protected by HTTPS (so call service via HTTPS not HTTP) and authentication, that is just added to SOAP headers. To get a sample you can switch off Transport security (switch to HTTP), capture actual data passed with sniffer (like WireShark) and make Java app send data in that form.

Comment: Does Java not have any proxy generation tools that can create the classes that construct the message properly? Similar to WSDL.exe in the .NET world?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Java library [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) to interact with the WCF service.

I think Axis has the ability to [generate Java service interaction code](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL) based on a WSDL (WSDL2Java).

Comment: How would you pass the credentials to the service using the Axis classes?