# java wcf client identified by a certificate SOAPFaultException

Tags: java, wcf, soap, https, certificate

I have an issue with implementing a client to a wcf service (run on IIS) over https, the client should be identified by a certificate.

If client being implemented in C# - it works fine. But if trying to implement it in java I have some soapfaultexception.

My steps were:
1. generate all needed entities via not secure wsdl

1. get certificate to identify mine and add it to keystore:

   "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -importkeystore  -srckeystore STSTestCert.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass STSTestCert  -deststorepass STSTestCert -destkeystore STSTestCert.jks
2. get certificate from the server (via browser) and add it to the truststore:

   "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias ststrust -file DEVWEB01.dev.qns.local.cer -destkeystore STSTestCert.jks
3. run the java application:

   "java -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol -    Djavax.net.debug=ssl  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=STSTestCert.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=STSTestCert  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=STSTestCert.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=STSTestCert -jar QuanisTest.jar https://XXX/XXX?wsdl"

I get the following log:

```
C:\Users\1\workspace\wsfexample\target>java -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol -Djavax.net.debug=ssl  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=STSTestCert.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=STSTestCert  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=STSTestCert.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=STSTestCert -jar QuanisTest.jar https://XXX/XXX?wsdl 
keyStore is : STSTestCert.jks
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
***
found key for : ststestcert42d35222-95bb-4742-903b-b937c8d8799c
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=STSTestCert
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 22968449806216710225497752109144878755673370049706550982038300678457357704947360314420538479370135402838232182690844484242628097129341692104140791435633221995214474484611109065339123593363421151991982869173035908895259027546127016671318511742131083747850409847716404435591004194757800222863577805104264933184015790099155606705832788529239312770261387589330421003086069991143116616048171938464442870190252229326206691209916229206809213249289351250819136425144878419918456807600891460332482275409728702056197072576033137510107386677977972112857357731917695194403001057957886262992664403571789554744227741153856152913439
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri May 06 13:23:26 EEST 2011,
               To: Sat May 05 19:23:26 EEST 2012]
  Issuer: CN=STSTestCert
  SerialNumber: [    7d5c807d c7c059b3 45ff03f8 60162db9]

Certificate Extensions: 2
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: A6 AA 21 FF 43 6E 90 CB   2A 1F 5D 90 DF EC 79 A5  ..!.Cn..*.]...y.
0010: 3B CD 8A 7D                                        ;...
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 4E 38 10 74 2A 9B 88 12   C9 DE F4 ED 67 95 70 6D  N8.t*.......g.pm
0010: 2E 65 56 E9 67 43 5F B8   A6 64 11 97 81 AF 95 29  .eV.gC_..d.....)
0020: EF DF 92 EE B4 34 FE FF   8C 65 D1 03 EA 68 E3 01  .....4...e...h..
0030: DA 80 DE D6 60 34 C4 DE   CD 66 DD E2 3A 2D B5 BA  ....`4...f..:-..
0040: C0 E9 21 42 F2 25 92 9D   5E BA 23 54 25 04 97 9D  ..!B.%..^.#T%...
0050: 59 76 E2 33 AC 03 90 88   9E 36 71 04 75 DD 7E F0  Yv.3.....6q.u...
0060: 82 75 3B CB 18 CE BE FD   D9 AD F5 5D A1 F7 C1 17  .u;........]....
0070: 2C AD FA 6A C4 EC FE BE   9D A1 FC 0D 14 C2 90 75  ,..j...........u
0080: 71 0D 37 B1 01 4B 6A DA   9C B1 AE 71 56 5A 65 4C  q.7..Kj....qVZeL
0090: 7F 0A F1 21 A4 7A 12 E6   80 AF 37 A7 92 84 14 C0  ...!.z....7.....
00A0: F7 C6 02 E4 79 CA 09 1B   91 A5 DF C8 FA BC D1 55  ....y..........U
00B0: 23 1A 1E CE 5D 19 86 13   83 F2 63 F2 B4 B3 E8 2A  #...].....c....*
00C0: D7 FB 08 29 BD 9A 8A CF   7C 50 48 45 D4 78 F2 AC  ...).....PHE.x..
00D0: C3 0D 4A 8A 7D 09 71 5F   C0 DA FD 19 56 9C 76 69  ..J...q_....V.vi
00E0: 5B B5 62 14 F0 F7 D8 AA   06 7B 93 82 FA 68 2A E4  [.b..........h*.
00F0: 61 F2 68 E8 A6 C9 35 49   CE ED A0 45 12 19 AF FD  a.h...5I...E....

]
***
trustStore is: STSTestCert.jks
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DEVWEB01.dev.qns.local
  Issuer:  CN=Quanis02, DC=qns, DC=local
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x526f1800000100000bf5
  Valid from Mon Feb 06 17:25:02 EET 2012 until Tue Feb 05 17:25:02 EET 2013

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=STSTestCert
  Issuer:  CN=STSTestCert
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x7d5c807dc7c059b345ff03f860162db9
  Valid from Fri May 06 13:23:26 EEST 2011 until Sat May 05 19:23:26 EEST 2012

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1332157371 bytes = { 63, 18, 25, 165, 142, 14, 244, 1, 14, 227, 50, 29, 78, 35, 156, 115, 191, 74, 174, 193, 209, 185, 147, 7, 127, 71, 106, 211 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 75
main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 101
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1669
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1332157370 bytes = { 81, 138, 253, 187, 72, 162, 134, 221, 201, 198, 164, 174, 32, 82, 109, 245, 193, 253, 168, 204, 215, 75, 59, 113, 201, 1, 129, 13 }
Session ID:  {103, 11, 0, 0, 210, 24, 89, 173, 235, 231, 153, 201, 209, 49, 14, 218, 226, 97, 83, 240, 16, 87, 171, 51, 79, 1, 61, 167, 86, 172, 5, 120}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Created:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=DEVWEB01.dev.qns.local
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 29424055442845100182950951585266127271921631119207852754022075382787715172423620759537480268531045831954620744099925778194145634066616862948861198661434224521747367480278853560135499066656353446473559007565450005358532786609676496384676754155589981649336076267751671656823332565466578060186500487885045277359237588131927310598032787808691595385530991095301637928904893952834743639035619583227127919434683665665359351285689260454499341943979506916974721470673454442099937197908223853100048736048404871663325953313860300437264643072804179816474287746350000127287179889675938899658794833379770139642801001487662781678747
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Mon Feb 06 17:25:02 EET 2012,
               To: Tue Feb 05 17:25:02 EET 2013]
  Issuer: CN=Quanis02, DC=qns, DC=local
  SerialNumber: [    526f1800 00010000 0bf5]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 10 1E 0E 00 4D 00 61   00 63 00 68 00 69 00 6E  .....M.a.c.h.i.n
0010: 00 65                                              .e


[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: D4 C3 AA 32 8C 6B BA AB   41 E7 AB E1 3B C7 B0 84  ...2.k..A...;...
0010: 05 8E 12 54                                        ...T
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 33 42 69 EB 41 93 C7 C5   99 60 B7 AF E8 B2 DF 56  3Bi.A....`.....V
0010: 3A 0F C9 71                                        :..q
]

]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: DEVWEB01.dev.qns.local
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: ldap:///CN=Quanis02(1),CN=PQNSOPS02,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=qns,DC=local?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
  serverAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: ldap:///CN=Quanis02,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=qns,DC=local?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 8B 1F CD E4 58 C9 C3 38   E3 09 07 6A E0 C1 06 EA  ....X..8...j....
0010: 48 F9 69 A2 B7 4F 58 2F   5E AD 32 38 EA 2C BD 03  H.i..OX/^.28.,..
0020: C8 28 CD 66 6B 1C AE 83   97 E7 C5 C9 6E 8B 5F C5  .(.fk.......n._.
0030: 63 E6 53 A8 41 76 BF 64   C4 B4 F3 2F B9 29 B9 65  c.S.Av.d.../.).e
0040: 9B F8 11 C0 DA 59 83 30   5C A5 5C 99 29 9A 96 CD  .....Y.0\.\.)...
0050: 9A B1 40 58 97 EF BC 06   98 FB 6D 00 48 25 21 FA  ..@X......m.H%!.
0060: 97 FC BD E1 68 4C 00 A6   21 77 F1 EC 77 72 A6 AC  ....hL..!w..wr..
0070: 75 F0 56 9F CA 2A 12 67   CC 74 E2 85 A1 20 6F 6F  u.V..*.g.t... oo
0080: 1B AE 98 52 AD 92 6E AB   33 58 25 71 BD 79 53 8D  ...R..n.3X%q.yS.
0090: C9 87 32 8B AC 49 B8 59   42 31 F4 BB DD AE CE B6  ..2..I.YB1......
00A0: AE A4 42 46 53 9D FD EE   4F F3 1F 81 26 A6 42 20  ..BFS...O...&.B 
00B0: 25 98 00 0F 4B 66 0E A6   0F 6C 0C 39 4F D6 ED C4  %...Kf...l.9O...
00C0: 54 CD 30 A1 83 1C 7A 39   C9 C6 77 F5 84 DB 43 9F  T.0...z9..w...C.
00D0: 45 41 88 06 75 EF 84 46   21 B6 01 DE 0D 42 40 63  EA..u..F!....B@c
00E0: 90 8B 6B 86 02 F8 5B 2F   FE 68 AC 6E 0B 8A EF 0A  ..k...[/.h.n....
00F0: 24 CA 89 0F 40 86 6E 06   B7 02 B9 4E 65 35 63 D9  $...@.n....Ne5c.
0100: 9E CC E3 9D 56 D0 FF F7   3E B9 31 D2 5B D8 A1 F3  ....V...>.1.[...
0110: 96 98 88 49 B6 1E 09 FE   30 68 9C 5E 8D F2 49 95  ...I....0h.^..I.
0120: 85 E1 76 8F B1 0A ED 37   56 2F 1F 0F 23 B2 FD B6  ..v....7V/..#...
0130: 1D 42 C3 DA 61 D3 E3 FF   12 73 7A BF FC 34 39 BD  .B..a....sz..49.
0140: E0 F2 4B 84 05 1E 17 53   2F D7 74 DC EB 6D 34 5E  ..K....S/.t..m4^
0150: 53 E7 C5 0B A5 36 F1 E0   A9 18 D7 A5 28 09 8D E7  S....6......(...
0160: 0C AD 7E F9 1A BB B7 DB   91 59 CF A9 54 68 88 C9  .........Y..Th..
0170: 28 8B 03 63 7F 8B D1 44   3B 9E 86 09 4E BC EC 2C  (..c...D;...N..,
0180: 56 2F D4 BA F9 7D 4C 30   E7 A9 B0 16 FD E2 47 70  V/....L0......Gp
0190: B8 01 42 FF 93 DF 9D 6E   53 1D B4 B0 C4 5E 33 63  ..B....nS....^3c
01A0: 4A 0C 89 E6 64 29 F2 91   12 D3 64 67 4E E1 C6 61  J...d)....dgN..a
01B0: D8 49 9B C5 54 3F 90 58   49 78 F3 21 A5 DF 9A 5A  .I..T?.XIx.!...Z
01C0: 06 BD FD A6 B4 91 DD 35   CD D6 FF 2F B4 BC FB 17  .......5.../....
01D0: A6 AB 34 17 38 CD 31 76   B3 A0 36 0E CD 60 EB 7E  ..4.8.1v..6..`..
01E0: 72 2C 13 27 B5 D7 8F D0   F4 EE CB CF 07 FB CD A7  r,.'............
01F0: EA 25 86 02 A4 45 87 2C   4F CD 0A 75 EB 14 1C 54  .%...E.,O..u...T

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=DEVWEB01.dev.qns.local
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 29424055442845100182950951585266127271921631119207852754022075382787715172423620759537480268531045831954620744099925778194145634066616862948861198661434224521747367480278853560135499066656353446473559007565450005358532786609676496384676754155589981649336076267751671656823332565466578060186500487885045277359237588131927310598032787808691595385530991095301637928904893952834743639035619583227127919434683665665359351285689260454499341943979506916974721470673454442099937197908223853100048736048404871663325953313860300437264643072804179816474287746350000127287179889675938899658794833379770139642801001487662781678747
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Mon Feb 06 17:25:02 EET 2012,
               To: Tue Feb 05 17:25:02 EET 2013]
  Issuer: CN=Quanis02, DC=qns, DC=local
  SerialNumber: [    526f1800 00010000 0bf5]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 10 1E 0E 00 4D 00 61   00 63 00 68 00 69 00 6E  .....M.a.c.h.i.n
0010: 00 65                                              .e


[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: D4 C3 AA 32 8C 6B BA AB   41 E7 AB E1 3B C7 B0 84  ...2.k..A...;...
0010: 05 8E 12 54                                        ...T
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 33 42 69 EB 41 93 C7 C5   99 60 B7 AF E8 B2 DF 56  3Bi.A....`.....V
0010: 3A 0F C9 71                                        :..q
]

]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: DEVWEB01.dev.qns.local
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: ldap:///CN=Quanis02(1),CN=PQNSOPS02,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=qns,DC=local?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
  serverAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: ldap:///CN=Quanis02,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=qns,DC=local?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 8B 1F CD E4 58 C9 C3 38   E3 09 07 6A E0 C1 06 EA  ....X..8...j....
0010: 48 F9 69 A2 B7 4F 58 2F   5E AD 32 38 EA 2C BD 03  H.i..OX/^.28.,..
0020: C8 28 CD 66 6B 1C AE 83   97 E7 C5 C9 6E 8B 5F C5  .(.fk.......n._.
0030: 63 E6 53 A8 41 76 BF 64   C4 B4 F3 2F B9 29 B9 65  c.S.Av.d.../.).e
0040: 9B F8 11 C0 DA 59 83 30   5C A5 5C 99 29 9A 96 CD  .....Y.0\.\.)...
0050: 9A B1 40 58 97 EF BC 06   98 FB 6D 00 48 25 21 FA  ..@X......m.H%!.
0060: 97 FC BD E1 68 4C 00 A6   21 77 F1 EC 77 72 A6 AC  ....hL..!w..wr..
0070: 75 F0 56 9F CA 2A 12 67   CC 74 E2 85 A1 20 6F 6F  u.V..*.g.t... oo
0080: 1B AE 98 52 AD 92 6E AB   33 58 25 71 BD 79 53 8D  ...R..n.3X%q.yS.
0090: C9 87 32 8B AC 49 B8 59   42 31 F4 BB DD AE CE B6  ..2..I.YB1......
00A0: AE A4 42 46 53 9D FD EE   4F F3 1F 81 26 A6 42 20  ..BFS...O...&.B 
00B0: 25 98 00 0F 4B 66 0E A6   0F 6C 0C 39 4F D6 ED C4  %...Kf...l.9O...
00C0: 54 CD 30 A1 83 1C 7A 39   C9 C6 77 F5 84 DB 43 9F  T.0...z9..w...C.
00D0: 45 41 88 06 75 EF 84 46   21 B6 01 DE 0D 42 40 63  EA..u..F!....B@c
00E0: 90 8B 6B 86 02 F8 5B 2F   FE 68 AC 6E 0B 8A EF 0A  ..k...[/.h.n....
00F0: 24 CA 89 0F 40 86 6E 06   B7 02 B9 4E 65 35 63 D9  $...@.n....Ne5c.
0100: 9E CC E3 9D 56 D0 FF F7   3E B9 31 D2 5B D8 A1 F3  ....V...>.1.[...
0110: 96 98 88 49 B6 1E 09 FE   30 68 9C 5E 8D F2 49 95  ...I....0h.^..I.
0120: 85 E1 76 8F B1 0A ED 37   56 2F 1F 0F 23 B2 FD B6  ..v....7V/..#...
0130: 1D 42 C3 DA 61 D3 E3 FF   12 73 7A BF FC 34 39 BD  .B..a....sz..49.
0140: E0 F2 4B 84 05 1E 17 53   2F D7 74 DC EB 6D 34 5E  ..K....S/.t..m4^
0150: 53 E7 C5 0B A5 36 F1 E0   A9 18 D7 A5 28 09 8D E7  S....6......(...
0160: 0C AD 7E F9 1A BB B7 DB   91 59 CF A9 54 68 88 C9  .........Y..Th..
0170: 28 8B 03 63 7F 8B D1 44   3B 9E 86 09 4E BC EC 2C  (..c...D;...N..,
0180: 56 2F D4 BA F9 7D 4C 30   E7 A9 B0 16 FD E2 47 70  V/....L0......Gp
0190: B8 01 42 FF 93 DF 9D 6E   53 1D B4 B0 C4 5E 33 63  ..B....nS....^3c
01A0: 4A 0C 89 E6 64 29 F2 91   12 D3 64 67 4E E1 C6 61  J...d)....dgN..a
01B0: D8 49 9B C5 54 3F 90 58   49 78 F3 21 A5 DF 9A 5A  .I..T?.XIx.!...Z
01C0: 06 BD FD A6 B4 91 DD 35   CD D6 FF 2F B4 BC FB 17  .......5.../....
01D0: A6 AB 34 17 38 CD 31 76   B3 A0 36 0E CD 60 EB 7E  ..4.8.1v..6..`..
01E0: 72 2C 13 27 B5 D7 8F D0   F4 EE CB CF 07 FB CD A7  r,.'............
01F0: EA 25 86 02 A4 45 87 2C   4F CD 0A 75 EB 14 1C 54  .%...E.,O..u...T

]
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 95 32 FD BD 0B E5   D2 FA AC 15 86 35 D4 BD  ...2.........5..
0010: BB 1E E8 6D D9 D7 70 EE   02 C5 DC 53 0F 88 BA 12  ...m..p....S....
0020: AD FB B4 3A 35 42 AC 49   95 84 03 7C 4B 0E CC C3  ...:5B.I....K...
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 4F 67 1C BB 3F 12 19 A5   8E 0E F4 01 0E E3 32 1D  Og..?.........2.
0010: 4E 23 9C 73 BF 4A AE C1   D1 B9 93 07 7F 47 6A D3  N#.s.J.......Gj.
Server Nonce:
0000: 4F 67 1C BA 51 8A FD BB   48 A2 86 DD C9 C6 A4 AE  Og..Q...H.......
0010: 20 52 6D F5 C1 FD A8 CC   D7 4B 3B 71 C9 01 81 0D   Rm......K;q....
Master Secret:
0000: 7E 34 BF B9 97 0A 35 F0   77 82 74 73 A3 6A 07 6E  .4....5.w.ts.j.n
0010: C4 A4 27 1B B9 D1 CF AF   6E B7 B0 44 65 B8 68 42  ..'.....n..De.hB
0020: C2 3E 49 AC 41 8C C9 F5   2F CD D7 4B 75 F0 87 29  .>I.A.../..Ku..)
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: B2 95 83 C5 E2 4A E9 9E   E5 26 C2 06 91 3E 8F F0  .....J...&...>..
0010: 45 F3 E4 CB                                        E...
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 16 74 51 FF CC CA 63 18   39 73 DE C8 B6 13 2F BC  .tQ...c.9s..../.
0010: 2A B9 2A 2E                                        *.*.
Client write key:
0000: 3C D6 E6 52 BF 30 A0 55   3B F6 E7 3B 78 D2 EB 6B  <..R.0.U;..;x..k
Server write key:
0000: D1 38 E1 71 00 B7 0F 50   63 7C E5 BC 1F 5F D7 88  .8.q...Pc...._..
Client write IV:
0000: 05 F6 FA 67 FA 81 33 7C   5B C0 67 4E 78 C9 13 25  ...g..3.[.gNx..%
Server write IV:
0000: DF 93 0A 93 C4 CA 14 83   88 F4 2C 33 16 F1 CA 74  ..........,3...t
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 57, 204, 166, 68, 236, 32, 196, 129, 218, 56, 112, 168 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 54, 177, 61, 73, 91, 252, 28, 165, 103, 97, 17, 35 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 240
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1936
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 240
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 7104
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 240
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 3344
connection established
service connected
java.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: an error occured when verifying security for the message.
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke
     at $Proxy36.getVersion
     at Main(Main.java:57)
```

My java code is:

```
   import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
   import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

   import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
   import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
   public class Main{
   private static final String SERVICE_NAME_STR = ...;
   private static final QName SERVICE_QNAME = ...
URL wsdlURL = null;
    try {
        wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
        System.out.println("using url " + wsdlURL);

        NucluesIntakeService ns = new NucluesIntakeService(wsdlURL,
                SERVICE_QNAME);
        System.out.println("connection established");
        INucluesIntakeService service = ns
                .getBasicHttpBindingINucluesIntakeService();
        System.out.println("service connected");
        System.out.println("\nservice version is " + service.getVersion());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have also tried to add these certificates to java default keystore without any success.

Here is the wsdl :

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:i0="http://matterhorn.quanis.com/bindings" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="NucluesIntakeService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:import namespace="http://matterhorn.quanis.com/bindings" location="https://XXX/XXX?wsdl=wsdl1"/>
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:service name="NucluesIntakeService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_INucluesIntakeService" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_INucluesIntakeService">
<soap:address location="http://XXX/XXX/NucluesIntakeService.svc/message"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_INucluesIntakeService1" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_INucluesIntakeService1">
<soap:address location="https://XXX/XXX/NucluesIntakeService.svc/message"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Thanks

Comment: BTW when checking IIS log I have noticed that in the "Recieved message over a channel" in message headers tree there was no security element, like in c# product

Comment: IIS is configured just to identify the client by certificate, and the client should identify the server by server ones.

Comment: It seems that this problem is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218135/use-java-to-access-a-wcf-service-with-transportwithmessagecredentials-username